# Build.scala:1: not found: object sbt

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am using sbt version 1.0

```
$ sbt version
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/harit/code/learningScala/project
[info] Set current project to learningScala (in build file:/Users/harit/code/learningScala/)
[info] 1.0
```

I am using `IntelliJ IDEA v14.1.3` for my project and the structure looks like

[image]

As you may see that project was not able to resolve `Build`. When I try command-line to run `sbt`, I see

```
$ sbt 
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/harit/code/learningScala/project
[info] Set current project to learningScala (in build file:/Users/harit/code/learningScala/)
> compile
[info] Updating {file:/Users/harit/code/learningScala/}learningscala...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/harit/code/learningScala/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /Users/harit/code/learningScala/Build.scala:1: not found: object sbt
[error] import sbt.Build
[error]        ^
[error] /Users/harit/code/learningScala/Build.scala:3: not found: type Build
[error] object MyBuild extends Build {
[error]                        ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed May 28, 2015 8:10:37 PM
>
```

I am very new to `Scala`, `sbt` so no idea what is going wrong with it

Comment: A small note on `sbt version`, `sbt version` will show you your project's version, `sbt --version` will show you the sbt's launcher version, and then the launcher will use whatever version is written under `project/build.properties` which you can also see with `sbt sbtVersion`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `MyBuild.scala` was at `root`. It should be inside `project` folder. I made that change and now it works. Thanks to `tpolecat` on IRC who helped me with this

[image]
[image]

```
> compile
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed May 28, 2015 8:20:57 PM
> compile
[info] Updating {file:/Users/harit/code/learningScala/}learningscala...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed May 28, 2015 8:21:22 PM
>
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. Didn't spot this crucial point in the documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a multi-project sbt build, and two of the projects were declaring two of the same val in their build.sbt files. I moved the duplicated val (s) to the Build.scala in the root project as def, and error stopped. Found the answer here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1465

example:  **val samza_gid = "org.apache.samza"** in build.sbt file became
  **def samza_gid = "org.apache.samza"** in the Build.scala file.